# Why did I lose 6 reputation after deleting a post with a negative score?

Tags: support

I deleted one of my answers because it had a score of -1 which brought a -2 reputation penalty to me.  However, instead of gaining 2 reputation, I lost 6 reputation.  What is going on?

Link to question here: [Is C minor i in the key of C minor?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/65671/is-c-minor-i-in-the-key-of-c-minor/77233#77233)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An upvoted answer gives you 10 rep. A downvoted answer gives you -2.

It looks like that answer had one upvote and two downvotes - a net +6 rep. When you deleted it you lost that +6.

One of the privileges you will hit at 1000 rep is the ability to see the vote counts on posts: If you ever need to know how many up- and downvotes you have on a post, click on the post score, and it will split out the totals for you.